# Как использовать url шаблон Django в ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django, url

Хочу в ajax запросе сделать перенаправление на другую страницу после авторизации. В уроках видела, что можно использовать язык шаблонов Django. Но у меня почему-то url строятся не корректно. В чем ошибка?
Запрос:

```
$("#singin").submit( function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        // Generate URL without "id" bit
    var url = '/' + "{% url 'course:index' %}" + '/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/user/login/',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'ok'){
                    document.location.href = url;
                }
            }
       });
    });
```

url:

```
app_name = 'course'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /course/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Результат работы:

```
Not Found: /{% url "course:index" %}/
```

[31/Jan/2017 12:05:32] "GET /%7B%%20url%20%22course:index%22%20%%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2368

Comment: У вас js-код находится в шаблоне?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как статичный файл прикреплен.

Comment: Тогда не удивительно, шаблонизатор его не обрабатывает, замена конструкции `{% url "course:index" %}` на url не происходит.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в таком случае нужно js-код переместить в шаблон? Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше их всё-таки разделять. А в шаблон можно вынести только часть js-кода, связанного с реверсом адресов. Посмотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу проблему можно решить таким способом:

**В статическом js-файле**

```
$("#singin").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'ok'){
                    document.location.href = window.urls['signin_success'];
                }
            }
       });
    });
```

**В шаблоне, в котором этот файл подключается**

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <!-- Самое начало -->
        <script>
            window.urls = {
                'signin_success': '{% url "course:index" %}',
                ...
            };
        </script>
        ...
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'auth:login' %}">
            ...
        </form>
        ...
        <!-- Самый конец -->
        <script src="наш_статичный_файл.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Библилотека [django-js-reverse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-js-reverse) умеет прокидывать пути описанные в джанге в клиентский js.

В итоге получится что-то вроде:

```
$("#singin").submit( function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/user/login/',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'ok'){
                    document.location.href = Urls['course:index']();
                }
            }
       });
    });
```